# Contiki OS Rime + IPv6

Tags: routing, ipv6

I have a network of sensors which run the RIME protocol with custom muli-hop connections. I intend to connect this network to an outside network (IPv6). But my question is that whether RIME and IPv6 are compatible with each other?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not. You could write your own adaptation layer to make it work with 6Lowpan (a lightweight implementation of IPv6), but it will be a huge amount of work.

Comment: Thank you, So is there any other way to connect my protocol that uses RIME to the internet (i.e. maybe if I use IPv4 on the outside Internet instead of IPv6) ?